# Google Sheets Appscript Conditional Formatting - Specifying Color

Tags: google-apps-script, conditional-formatting, google-sheets-api

I am new to Apps Script, I hope someone can help.  I am defining the background colour of a cell in a conditional formatting request.  I want to specify Cornflower Blue, which seems to be hex code #4a86e8.  This seems to translate to RGB: 74, 134, 132.  Unfortunately, I can only see a technique to specify my conditional formatting background colour using rgb 0-1 values.  dividing each or the rgb(0-255) values by 255 gives 0.2902, 0.5255, 0.9098 but when I code these values in the resulting colour is only a (good) approximation to the required color.  Can I specify the hex colour or rgb(0-255) colour instead of the following definition?:

"format": {"backgroundColor":  {"red": 0.2902,"green": 0.5255,"blue": 0.9098}}

(If the answer is yes - please can someone direct me to the documentation that explains how to specify Conditional Formatting colours using alternate conventions).

Many thanks!

Comment: You can set colors with standard RGB color codes [according to the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setBackgroundRGB(Integer,Integer,Integer)).

Comment: Thank you Brian, yes colours may be specified in RGB notation.  My specific question relates to so doing in the context of the Conditional Format batch update.  Can the following be expressed using RGB notation syntax: "format": {"backgroundColor": {"red": 0.2902,"green": 0.5255,"blue": 0.9098}}

Comment: I think your question is unclear. Are you trying to set conditional formatting _once_ for a range via script, or are you trying to use a script to test for a value? Plus, the mechanisms via Sheets API vs Google Apps Script are different, but you have both tagged. Which approach are you trying to use?

Comment: Brian, apologies.  To clarify I am using Sheets API.  I now have a solution.  My solution uses an installable trigger event handler, fired in response to the onOpen() event.  The event handler invokes a function which deletes all conditional formatting then adds the approved conditional formatting using a Batch Update request.  Because an installable trigger has been used my account authorization persists for all users.  Every day is a school day.  Thanks very much for your input

Answer (score -1):

I've found the best way to accomplish conditional formatting is to use the built-in conditional formatting feature in Google Sheets (rather than writing a script for it). If none of the built-in conditions meet your requirements you can always write a custom formula for it using standard Sheets formulas.

If you have to use App Scripts in your situation, the best way to probably accomplish what you are trying to do is through the `.copyFormatToRange` method. The documentation for that is here:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyformattorangesheet-column-columnend-row-rowend

In Google Sheets, you can use hex code to specify color by going to **Fill color** icon and selecting **Custom...** In App Scripts, you can specify background color in hex with `.setBackground("#4a86e8")` or in RGB with `.setBackgroundRGB(74, 134, 132)`. Documentation is here:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundcolor

Comment: Thank you Dan.  I specifically want to use a script to maintain the conditional formatting.  My intention is to avoid conditional formats being changed (often inadvertently) by a user.  I appreciate how to use RGB notation with the .setBackgroundRGB.   My query was in regard of the Conditional Fromating request:  "format": {"backgroundColor": {"red": 0.2902,"green": 0.5255,"blue": 0.9098}}.  In regard of  .copyFormatToRange  - does this really copy conditional formatting (which would be useful but only if I could be confident of the conditional formatting of the source ) or just the formats ?